# What anime is this where everyone has a virtual world from glasses?

Tags: dennou-coil

So a few years ago, I saw an anime where everyone had special glasses that basically superimposed a virtual world onto the real world (so, erm, Google Glass but better). I don't remember it very well, but I think there was a very large round red object related—does anyone have any idea what anime this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Odds are you're thinking of **Dennou Coil**.

The large round red thing is a Searchmaton / Satchii. These creepy little buggers:

[image: Satchiis galore]

> Dennō Coil (電脳コイル Dennō Koiru?, lit. Electric Brain Coil or Computer Coil), Coil—A Circle of Children, is a Japanese science fiction anime television series depicting a near future where semi-immersive augmented reality (AR) technology has just begun to enter the mainstream. The series takes place in the fictional city of Daikoku, a hotbed of AR development with an emerging city-wide virtual infrastructure. It follows a group of children as they use AR glasses to unravel the mysteries of the half real, half Internet city, using a variety of illegal software tools, techniques, and virtual pets to manipulate the digital landscape.

<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denn%C5%8D_Coil)</sup>